# How does addEventListener() receive the event object param automatically?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Consider this code below:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(event) { ... })
```

The addEventListener method works in such a way that its second param is a function into which the `event` object is automatically passed as a first parameter.

How does addEventListener do this? Is there a programming pattern involved?

Answer (score 0):

Its called a callback where in you call the function parameter inside the function you are running

```
var success = function(event){
    console.log(event);
}

function sample(data, callback){
    //peform data manipulation here
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    callback(json);
}

var json = localStorage.getItem('user_data');

sample(json, success);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see there as `event` is just the name of the variable that will be used later when the event is triggered, it's not that the event is already being passed as a parameter. You are passing a function that, when the event is triggered, will be called with the actual event.

You could an object that implements EventListener that has a method handleEvent which will receive the event as the first parameter.

Maybe it's easier to understand if you use pass a variable with the function:

```
myCallback = function(event) {
  // do something with event
}

element.addEventListener('click', myCallback);
```

Iternally (really simplified), it saves a reference to that function and calls it with the actual event (something like `myCallback(event)`) when the user clicks the element to actually run the function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener